# How do I compose nested case classes populated with async mongodb queries in play framework

Tags: scala, playframework, future

I have been trying to convert mongodb queries I have working with await to using totally async.  The problem is, I cannot find any examples or get code working to populate a list of objects where for each object there is a nested find returning futures.

I have seen examples for a single object, such as

```
val user = mongoDao.getUser(id)
val address = mongoDao.getAddress(user.id)
```

for that I see for comprehension works just fine.  However, I have a list of objects (similar to users) and I cant seem to get the code right.

What I need to do is get all the users in an async manner, then when they complete, get all the addresses and populate a field (or create a new case class.)

```
val usersFuture : Future[List[User]] = mongoDao.getUsers()
val fullFutures : Future[List[FullUser]] = usersFuture.map(users: List[User] => {
  users.map(user: User => {
    val futureAddress : Future[Address] = mongoDao.getAddress()
    // Now create a object 
    futureAddress.map(address: Address) {
      FullUserInfo(user, address)
    }
  }
}
```

So, I'd like to end up with a Future[List[FullUser]] that I can return to the play framework.  I've included the cutdown I've tried.

thanks

````
// OBJECTS HERE
case class Outer(id: Int, name: String)
case class Inner(id: Int, name: String)
case class Combined(id: Int, name: String, inner: Inner)

// FAKE DAO to reproduct
@Singleton
class StatInner  @Inject()( implicit val  ec: ExecutionContext) {
  def outer() = {
    Future {
      val lb = new ListBuffer[Outer]()
      Thread.sleep(1000)
      println("Done")
      for (id <- 1 to 5) {
        lb += Outer(id, s"Hello $id")
      }
      lb.toList
    }
  }

  def inner(id: Int) : Future[Inner] = {
    Future {
      Thread.sleep(1000)
      Inner(id, s"inner $id")
    }
  }
}


// CODE to query that is not working

  def nestedTree = Action.async {
    val statInner : StatInner  = new StatInner()
    val listouter : Future[List[Outer]] = statInner.outer()
    val combined = listouter.map((listOuter : List[Outer]) => {
      listOuter.flatMap((outer: Outer) => {
        val futInner : Future[Inner] = statInner.inner(outer.id)
        futInner.map((inner: Inner) => {
          Combined(outer, inner)
        })
      })
    })
    combined.map(Json.toJson(_))

  }
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Use `Future.{flatMap.sequence}`:

```
val usersFuture: Future[List[User]] = mongoDao.getUsers()
val fullFutures: Future[List[FullUser]] = usersFuture.flatMap { users =>
  Future.sequence(users.map { user =>
    mongoDao.getAddress().map { adress =>
      FullUserInfo(user, address)
    }
  })
}
```